# Number of max open files for a process stays low

Tags: linux, ubuntu, file-descriptors

I have a process running on a ubuntu under a user which its ulimit is 400000 for both -Hn and -Sn options.
The /etc/security/limits.conf value for that user is 100000.

However, when I execute `cat /proc/5660/limits | grep files` (the pid is 5660) I get:

```
Max open files            4032                 4032                 files
```

The process by the way is redis.

What else should I set?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm have a suspicion that the fact this process runs under supervisord might cause this. When running redis from the command line it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found this article (look at the bottom): http://www.elasticsearch.org/tutorials/too-many-open-files/

Apparently supervisord is the problem.